# Ending program with a stop button

Tags: c#, selenium, backgroundworker

I am trying to get my program to close when clicking a stop button.

I am using a background worker, but whenever i click stop, the form hangs and then i get an error saying "An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code"

My stop button click code is

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        }
        Application.Exit();
        driverGC.Quit();
    }
```

The RunWorkerCompleted is:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You've cancelled the backgroundworker!");
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error:" + e.Error.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Done!");
        }
    }
```

Yes, i have it supporting cancellation. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Just add `backgroundWorker1.Dispose();` after `backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();`. I think the exception is due to `driverGC.Quit();` this line. So please tell me what is `driverGC`?

Comment: driverGC is just the name for my webdriver. But i will try the backgroundWork1.Dispose() and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
this.Application.Close();
```

Comment: I dont have an option for application? It does not show green when i use this.Application.Close() but if I do Application.Exit() it is green.

Comment: Try that Maybe it will give you a hint.

Comment: I am already using Application.Exit() but the problem is when i click the Stop button, the program hangs and i get an error because the program is still trying to run, but the driver has closed.